# React carousel : why images are coming in list view rather into carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel

I am facing a problem of placing images inside carousel . Currently each images are coming separately rather sliding into carousel.

Please help me to rectify my mistake.

## Jxs

```
render()
    {
        var banquetImg = this.props.IMG_BASE + this.props.RESTAURANT_BANNER_PATH
      return (
        <div className="photosSection">
          {
            this.props.banquetImageList.length != 0
            ?
              <div className="body">
                <div className="row">
                    {
                    this.props.banquetImageList.map(function (row, i)
                    { 
                      return(
                                    <Carousel showArrows={true} key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId}>
                                          <div key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId} className={"row"}>
                                            <img src={banquetImg + row.FileName} key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId}/>
                                            <p className="get-final-price">Get Final Price</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </Carousel>
                                      )
                      }, this)
                  }
                          </div>

              </div>
              :
                ""
          } 
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Question is unclear please add a jsfiddle or codesandbox of the current situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map `banquetImageList` into `Carousel`,

```
<div className="row">
  <Carousel showArrows={true} key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId}>
     {this.props.banquetImageList.map((row, i) =>
         <div key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId} className={"row"}>
             <img src={banquetImg + row.FileName} key={row.RestaurantAttachmentId}/>
              <p className="get-final-price">Get Final Price</p>
         </div>
     )}
  </Carousel>   
</div>
```